# Date/Time Axes In gnuplot

Tags: date, time, gnuplot

I'm unable to get date/time to work in `gnuplot`.  Here's what seems right to me, errors described below.

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%j/%H:%M:%S"
#set xrange ["2016-349/00:56:00":"2016-349/00:57:00"]
set format x "%H:%M:%S"

plot "-" using ($1):($2) with lines
2016-349/00:56:26.560000 0.587785252292582
2016-349/00:56:27.560000 1.59702608337727e-13
2016-349/00:56:28.560000 -0.587785252292324
e

pause mouse any
```

With `set xrange` commented out as shown, I get this warning.

```
Warning: empty x range [2016:2016], adjusting to [1995.84:2036.16]
```

and the x-axis doesn't appear to be based on the range of the data, with ticks from 00:33:15 to 00:34:00.  The resulting plot is a vertical line at 00:33:36, but the points are part of a sine wave.

Uncommenting `set xrange`, I get this error instead.

```
line 6: all points y value undefined!
```

I get the same behavior with `gnuplot` 4.2 patchlevel 6, and 5.0 patchlevel 1.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
plot "-" using ($1):($2) with lines
```

You can use $ only in expressions, otherwise just use numbers itself:

```
plot "-" using 1:2 with lines
```

Comment: That fixed it, but I don't understand why.  Isn't `($1)` a valid expression?

Comment: Also, to keep my example simple, I deleted a line that's in my original, `set datafile missing "?"`.  I want a gap in the plot when there's a question mark in either data column, and thought the parentheses were needed to get that.

Comment: `$1` is a shortcut for `column(1)`  which parsed the column as number. Only `timecolumn(1)` would parse a time. With only `1` the choice between those two is made automatically.